# Get the resolution of the figures by LaTeX

Tags: resolution

Is there a way to get the resolution in PPI (pixel per inch) of the figures inserted in my document (e.g. by `\includegraphics`) directly by LaTeX? I mean something like printing the resolution value at the margin of the figure.

**Note.** I mean the resolution of the output of the figure in my document, not the resolution of the figure's file.